# Translation of Arguments from Propositional Logic to Predicate Logic

Tags: propositional-logic, predicate-logic

How exactly does this work? What can we assume stays the same, what changes?

Take for an example this (valid) argument:

1. A & ~C
2. ~C > ~D
3. ~D > B
4. ∴ B

Now let us take rewrite it according to the (simplified) notation of predicate logic:

1. (Ex)(Ax & ~Cx)
2. (x)(~Cx > ~Dx)
3. (x)(~Dx > Bx)
4. ∴ (Ex)Bx

Am I right in saying that these arguments, though given different codification, are identical? That is, can be expressed in exactly the same way using natural language?

Comment: Re your "What can we assume stays the same, what changes?", truth value (object) stays the same, the information abstraction level changes from 0th order to 1st order, so predicate logic can express more. Of course historically logicians before Pierce/Frege could deal with almost all meaningful philosophical tasks via syllogistic propositional logic  such as Aristotle and Stoic syllogisms...

Comment: It does not work that way... You can translate a natural language argument either in porp logic or in predicate logic.

Comment: Translating your symbolic propositional argument into a quantificational argument (what you are referring to as "predicate logic") by adding quantifiers to the statements seems to me misguided. If there was a natural language argument, it's possible its statements could be expressed with higher fidelity using the latter than the former, but as it is, you already have a completely well-formed quantificational argument, because predicate logic just is an extensional of propositional logic: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2569230/463355. Your argument is already valid in predicate logic.

Comment: If you want to rewrite a prop argument in predicate logic you have to replace **uniformly** prop variable with *atoms*: if **B** is **(Ex)Bx** in 4, then 3 must be e.g. **(~(x)Dx > (Ex)Bx)**

Comment: Alternatively, replace prop letters with predicates (open formulas) and consider **every** line of the resulting argument universally quantified.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something you cannot do without additional information. It is not possible to "rewrite" proposition logic formulas that represent full sentences, using the more detailed resources of predicate logic, unless you know the *sub-sentential structure* of the original sentence.(as one commentator above points out,since most predicate logics are extensions of propositional logic, they are already a part of predicate logic)

Just take as simple statement symbolized as "P" in propositional logic. Keep in mind that "P" represents a full sentence which can be any sentence.

The question

```
 "How can I represent "P" using the more detailed,fine-grained resources of predicate logic?"
```

cannot be answered without knowing what "P" stands for (and what kind of predicate logic system we are using, but let us ignore that for simplicity).

If "P" stands for the sentence: "John loves Mary", the predicate logic representation would be something like:

```
 *Ljm* (where 'L' is a 2-place predicate and 'j' and 'm' are individual constants)
```

If "P" stands for the sentence: "Some fish can jump" the predicate logic representation would be something like:

```
 *∃x (Fx and Jx)*
```

If "P" stands for the sentence: "All humans are mortal" the predicate logic representation would be something like:

```
 *∀x (Hx --> Dx)*
```

You get the idea. Without knowing the internal structure of the original sentence, there is no simple "rewrite".

Answer (score 0):

On most reasonable notions of identity, the two arguments are not identical.

First, on the level of syntax: clearly, the letters are not the same- qua token and qua type. Second, since the semantics of first order logic are different from prop logic, they are not the same. This is easy to see: we give the language expressed in OP a typical model-theoretic semantics, then A corresponds to a predicate of 0 arity in the first argument, and corresponds to a predicate of 1 arity in the second. Hence the semantics are not equivalent either.

Can they be expressed the exact same way in natural language? That is, does there exist some argument A in language L such that via translations T1, T2, it takes the syntactic forms or satisfies the arguments above? Possibly (although I have not worked it out), at least in the semantic case this probably just ends up as Putnams' model theoretic argument. But if you give that answer in a mathematical logic class, don't expect to get credit!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can pretty much always translate from predicate logic to propositional logic because, in a sense, that's what you're doing every time you instantiate. But going the other way around doesn't really work out as well. That's why folks came up with predicate logic in the first place. It lets you talk about things you can't using just propositional logic.

**1. What do you mean by "In a sense, you're translation from Predicate to Propositional every time you instantiate"?**

Well, let's give an example.

For all people x, if x walks in the rain and x doesn't have an umbrella, then x gets wet.

[image]

Thus by universal instantiation, for an arbitrary frank, if frank is in the rain and doesn't have an umbrella, then he gets wet.

[image]

or

[image]

Which is pretty much interchangeable with a propositional sentence. That's why, once we instantiate we use all the normal propositional logic rules.

For example, let's assume that frank isn't wet.

Then we can infer using typical propositional rules (denying consequent, DeMorgan's law, etc.) that either he wasn't in the rain or he had an umbrella.

[image]

Then we can universally instantiate to conclude that (since our choice of frank was arbitrary), for any person x, if x is not wet, then x didn't walk out in the rain or x has an umbrella.

[image]

The first and last operation (instantiating from general people to specifically frank and generalizing from frank to everyone) can't be done with propositional logic, but all the stuff in between pretty much WAS prop. logic.

In fact, EVERY sentence that's grammatical in propositional logic is grammatical in predicate logic (because just because you can have quantifiers in pred. logic, doesn't mean EVERY prove HAS to use them).

**2. But why can't I go the other way?**

To illustrate why you can't really translate from Predicate to Propositional (translation, why predicate sentences with quantifiers can't be translated into propositional logic).

Let's look at your first predicate sentence above (I'll just add some names to things to make it more intuitive).

[image]

There exists an animal x such that x is a dog and x doesn't have four legs.

As it stands, there is NO grammatical way to express this sentence in propositional logic. If I try to separate it into two propositions like you have above:

[image]

The closest I can get to even approximating that would be to say that A means: "There is a Dog"
and that C means "Some dog has four legs"

But saying "There is a dog and it's not true that some dog has four legs" is NOT the same thing as saying "There is some dog that doesn't have four legs"

**3. Conclusion:**

So, in summary
You can ALWAYS express instantiated predicate sentences as propositions. And vice versa.

[image]
"Christopher is angry and Christopher is belligerent."

As far as I can figure right now, you can probably express individual predicates with quantifiers as propositions, but you lose information since once you go into proposition land, you can't instantiate anymore.

[image]

BUT, if you have a quantifier operating on TWO predicates, then there's no way to translate that sentence from predicate logic to propositional logic.